# Empty file after saving...?

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

Code below is working, but after opening  - there are No features   in  shp file.
What can be a problem?

```
import osgeo, os
from osgeo import ogr, gdal

shpFile = r'C:\Users\ReBurns.shp'

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

ptsDS = driver.Open(shpFile)
ptsLayer = ptsDS.GetLayer()

#Passing criteria  to select polygons:    
myQuery = 'Area_ha > 39000.00'
ptsLayer.SetAttributeFilter(myQuery)
print ptsLayer
ptsLayer.GetFeatureCount()

#Save selected features to disk 
outds = driver.CreateDataSource(r'C:\Users\ReBurns111.shp')
outlyr = outds.CopyLayer(ptsLayer,'ReBurns111.shp')
```

Got error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-167-1e169b0c7c9c>", line 44, in <module>
    outlyr = outds.CopyLayer(ptsLayer,'ReBurns111.shp')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CopyLayer'
```

No selected files, but how to pass  selected by criterias?

Comment: You read and write the same file? Does it work if they are different?

Comment: No actually I just change output name,  If they different   it does not work also.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works, just need   to wait  few minutes   after   code exercise.

Comment: To save and close the dataset you need to dereference it,  i.e `del outds` or `outds=None` https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#Savingandclosingdatasetsdatasources